# session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) session_start():

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have upgrade php version from PHP 7 to PHP 7.1.
After That I am not able to open phpmyadmin. I am getting following error.

Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

```
session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)

session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: /var/cpanel/php/sessions/php)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I know this thread is a little old but for anyone who still need a solution, check to see if the "tmp" directory used by the system is present

For cPanel users, make sure the /home/$username/tmp or /home/$username/etc (credit: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/phpmyadmin-error.610207/post-2492163) are present. If not, create them or else sessions will not be created for any phpmyadmin user.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a **tmp** folder at Home.
Inside **/example/websitename** folder and it's gonna work correctly.