# phpMyAdmin Database Not found

Tags: php, cpanel

*Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.
session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)
session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: )*

Got this message in Cpanel! I found some answer on how to fix it but the problem is I can't find the tmp file in my home directory. No backups :( is there any other way to fix it?

Please, I hope someone could help me. Thank you in advance.

Elsa

Comment: This is not about mysql, this is about php's session handling.

Comment: contact your hosting provider. they can help you in this case

Comment: Searching for your error msg turns up some suggestions, including the already linked duplicate, and eg [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58336354/session-start-opensession-file-o-rdwr-failed-no-such-file-or-directory-2) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55390190/when-i-send-value-from-a-page-to-another-page-using-session-the-following-error) ... A common answer is that PHP's session dir is missing.  As you mention you can't find "the tmp file",  it seems possible you have the same problem.  Check the session dir in `php.ini`, make sure it exists.  See the duplicates.