# phpmyadmin error after updating to php 8.2

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

i was using phpmyadmin before, everything was good, but i changed php version in server from 7.2 to 8.2 then i got this error
[image]

i didn't find any solution

```
Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)

session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php80)
```

i tried to create tmp directory but didn't work

Comment: see there, the problem is the same : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58336354/session-start-opensession-file-o-rdwr-failed-no-such-file-or-directory-2

Comment: @svgta thanks i tried to create tmp file as they answered him, but didn't work for me

Comment: It's a tmp directory you have to create, not a file.

Comment: @svgta sorry it's mistyped file but i did create a directory already as they said and i gave permission both read - write to that directory
still same problem

Answer (score 0):

the cause of the problem was two files

[image]

after deleting these files it worked probably without any issues..

these files was on server that has Cpanel i was using before, i moved to CloudWays i copied the whole project so it came with it.

the solution for my problem: i did created tmp file and set read and write permissions
as showing here

> [session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) session_start():](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58336354/session-start-opensession-file-o-rdwr-failed-no-such-file-or-directory-2)

then deleted these two files.

```
.htaccesss 
.user.ini
```